# Generic type is lost when using an intersection of the expected interface

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extend a generic interface and use that result on a function, expecting TS to infer the generic from its params. Thing is, it only works when the param is a pure instance of the interface, not an extension of it. And for extensions of that interface, it only works if cast it or if I'm explicit with the generic type on the function signature.

Here's the code:

```
type Route<T = {}> = {
  path: string
}

type Params = {
  a: string,
  b: string
}

const someRoute: Route<Params> = {
  path: '/:a/:b'
}

type InnerParams = {
  c: string
}

const innerRoute: Route<Params & InnerParams> = {
  path: '/:a/:b/:c'
}

const routing = Object.assign(someRoute, { innerRoute })

function build<T> (route: Route<T>) {
  return (params: T) => `${route.path} --> ${JSON.stringify(params)}`
}


const thisWorks = build(routing.innerRoute) // OK! (params: Params & InnerParams) => string

const thisAlsoWorks = build(routing as Route<Params>) // OK! (params: Params) => string
const thisWorksToo = build<Params>(routing) // OK! (params: Params) => string

const thisDoesnt = build(routing) // not ok... (params: unknown) => string
```

Same code is here if you wanna play with it: https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-extending-generics-3w38z

Problem is, I don't get a type-safe function from the currying `build` function response. So I don't get type checking on it. Because it wrongly infers `unknown` from a type that is an extension of the type it expects.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See TypeScript [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--). Make sure to set `T` somewhere inside `Route` like `type Route<T = {}> = {params?: T; path: string}` and it now should work.

Comment: It does! I didn't know that, thanks!